# How to add a class to the element class in EXTJs

Tags: extjs, highcharts

I'm using a chart to render a piechart for my app. I have:

```
Ext.query('.highcharts-container')
```

that gives me an array of highchart-containers and I'd like to add a custom class to every one of them to add some custom css. I tried:

```
Ext.query('.highcharts-container').addCls("test")
```

but says "addCls" is not a function.
below is the img of how it looks:

[image]
and accord to the answers below, i tried adding it in seperate app, and it works, but for some reason in this case it constant shows undefined.no clue whts going on?

Comment: Note that the fiddle you posted is invalid, it has syntax errors in it.

Comment: Look at the log, there are no elements that match 'd'. Anyway, unless you post a real test case we can't help, can't go guessing every possible thin that might have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext.query will return an array of matching components.  If you're sure there will always be exactly 1 item in the array, you can use:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.highcharts-container')[0].addCls("test")
```

Otherwise, you should loop through the items and add the class to each component.

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('.highcharts-container').forEach(function (item) {
    item.addCls("test");
});
```

Comment: I tried the first case: it err: Ext.query(...)[0].addCls is not a function. also when i tried the second ex: it says: Ext.query("...").each is not a function, is this some version issue?

Comment: It should be `forEach` instead of `each`.  Answer is corrected.  You could also use `Ext.ComponentQuery.query('chart')` if these are the only charts you are using.

Comment: sure, the forEach solved, but still the "addCls" err keeps coming. i still get this: "TypeError: item.addCls is not a function(…)"..is there another way?

Comment: Can you post a simplified version of your code at [https://fiddle.sencha.com](https://fiddle.sencha.com)

Comment: Basically I want to able to add a class anywhere in teh prichart func, so that i can use to add customize styling https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1k7g

Answer (score 1):

`Ext.query` returns an array. Instead, use `Ext.select` which returns a `CompositeElement`. It lets you run `Ext.dom.Element` methods on a group of elements:

`Ext.select('.highcharts-container').addCls("test");`

Comment: says undefined again..is there something wrong with the version if extjs im using?

Comment: I doubt it. I suggest you post a test case. Here's `Ext.select` adding a class: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1k7j